# need setup common parameters in VS load test

Tags: visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I will do some load test for some webservice and I create multiple .webtest projects. Each project has some common parameters.  Is there any way we can setup the common parameters that can pass to all projects?
for example:

```
project_WS_call_1: has context Parameters: 
website_url=http://google.com 
username=test 
password=test1234

project_WS_call_2: has context Parameters: 
website_url=http://google.com 
username=test 
password=test1234
...
```

for multiple projects have the same context parameters. once these parameters change, I have to modify them one by one.  I wish there is a way to setup these parameter in higher level, if I change them once, each project will get the changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the values into a text file (you choose the format: xml or json or ini or whatever). Have a plugin that runs when the test starts, it reads the text file and writes the wanted values into context parameters.

If your web tests run from a load test then the code could be in the [start up method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.loadtesting.loadtest.loadteststarting.aspx). The load test context parameters are passed into the web test [overwriting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406971.aspx) any existing value.

If you do not use a load test then the code could be in the `PreWebTest` of a [web test plugin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191.aspx).

Remember that the web test editor has a "parameterise web servers" command that converts most urls in the test into context parameters.